# how to refresh one object with a new id generated by a trigger en db and return the new id

Tags: hibernate, entity, pojo, persist, .refresh

This is my entity. I tried to use sequence but my DB uses a trigger to call a Sequele.nextval. .Save of hiberte returns me the nextval but the trigger when try to insert add the next vale[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nwwf6.png)

Here I'm trying to use refresh [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wx4RT.png) is my dao.

Comment: Please post your code as formatted text, not as images.